# Package path for okhttp3.OkHttpClient or com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gradlew, okhttp

I'm building Google Maps API jar following [GitHub directions](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/) :

```
./gradlew jar
```

But when creating context:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("....")
```

I'm getting a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
```

This issue was reported [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/52), and Google's gurus just recommended building project with gradle or maven, which I don't want to do.

Instead, I tried to just import okhttp-3.2.0.jar using [various methods in their github repository](https://github.com/square/okhttp)

But for some reason, the jar includes 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient' not the 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient' which I need.

What can I to make the code run? Is there a way to compile Google Maps API with all the dependencies? Is there a way to compile okhttp so that the package is com.squareup.okhttp instead of okhttp3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to get version 2.x of OkHttp which uses the `com.squareup.okhttp.*` package. In order for version 1/2 and version 3 to coexist in the same classpath the package name of classes was changed for versions 3.x.

You can download jars of version 2.x from Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.squareup.okhttp%22%20AND%20a%3A%22okhttp%22 ('jar' link on the right).